# Включить монитор bcm43227 aircrack-ng

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Никак не получается включить монитор для сетевой карты bcm43227.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

[В официальной документации](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=faq&DokuWiki=2724uq54nkppe01d6jf5ir8876#why_do_i_get_ioctl_siocgifindex_failedno_such_device) сказано, что надо сначала включить интрфейс в самом `aircrack-ng`

А [тут](https://askubuntu.com/a/340090/457538) советуют обновить прогу до последней версии.